# Need to upload entire folders into gitlab from a windows machine -- command line not available

Tags: windows, gitlab

I am trying to establish a gitlab repository.  I have to work from a Windows machine.  I do not have a Linux emulator. I do not have gitlab-runner.  I cannot install either of these things (until the software people take three months to analyze their "suitability").  So, AFAICT, my only option is a web browser.  What I need to do is upload entire folders.  If i do this one file at a time I will be at this forever.  The browser isn't letting me do it.  It only wants one folder at a time.  I have looked around the internet and it seems that some people are convinced that you can upload entire folders with the gitlab drag and drop.  Others say no.  It's not working for me.  Am I doing something wrong?  Anyone have any ideas for other alternatives?

Comment: Ask “work” if they will install VMware Workstation for you. Then you can build whatever machine you need.

Comment: That's a thought.  It'll take them forever.  Will think on it.  Thanks.